# How to process data synchronously or wait until callback in visualforce remote action?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, remote-action, bootstrap

I'm trying to get data from remote action from a mouseover and display the popup. I have tried below code to pass the data in bootstrap tooltip/popovers.

```
 <script>
    function showPopup(recId,e)
  {  
    var res='';
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ControllerClass.getData}',
        recId,"{!record.Id}",
        function (result, event) {
        if(event.status)
          res=result;
        $('.li').popover("destroy").popover({content:res, placement: "bottom", template: '<div class="popover" style="width:250px; font-size:12px"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
                 });
        },{ buffer: false}
      );     
  }
</script>
```

I am using mouseover event to fire JS function and from the function making a remote action call and setting the tooltip content using **triggers: hover/click**. 
My observations are:

I. If I use `mouseover` to call JS function and use `trigger: click` in tooltip I see this working. I believe the fraction of second I take to click by the time callback is processed.

II. If I use `mouseover` to call JS function and use `trigger: hover` in tooltip then it doesn't work and content is not available for tooltip.

My requirement is to show bootstrap tooltip/popover on hover. I am using a `repeat` tag to generate a list of items and passing ids in remote action call.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!recs}" var="b">
  <li onmouseover="showPopup('{!b.id}',event)" onmouseout="hidePopup()"> 
{!b.Name}</li> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Please suggest anyway to fix this or any alternative approach.

Comment: have you tried onmouseenter?

Comment: Hover is the only option available for tooltips and by the time content is set callback is not processed.